# ABP.IO Blazor Template - Tenant login fails without error message

Tags: abp

I am working on a brand new ABP.IO solution with Blazor UI template. I'm **unable to login to a tenant**.

To replicate the issue follow below steps:

- Run DbMigrator to create host db
- Run web application and log into host
- Added first tenant from UI
- Run DbMigrator to create tenant db
- Cleared browser cache
- Run web application and log into tenant

  - This is where I get **error: There was an error trying to log you in: '' on login**.

I want to mention that I am using a SQL Account on my connection string to the host DB and to the tenant DB. This SQL login has been granted dbo permissions to both DBs and the DBmigrator console app uses the same connection string and it is able to perform all operations without any issues.

Comment: perhaps check the log file?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you manage to fix for this problem?

Comment: @hpatel no I did not.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/7518#issuecomment-769657228