# ABP.IO Sample Angular/Blazor Application- Tenant with separate DB login issue

Tags: identityserver4, abp

I created apps with ABP.IO framework with Angular/Blazor UI templates. I am able to compile and run the app successfully in Visual Studio 2019. Everything looks to be working fine except Multi-tenancy with separate database per tenant.

When I create a new tenant with shared database, I works perfectly.
However, if I create a tenant and provide a connection string for a separate database, there seems to be issues.

- The database for new tenant is created after running the migration
  project.
- Before login, I am able to switch the tenant.
- After entering username and password, Angular app shows the spinner
  icon loading forever.
- The Blazor app shows an error message: **There was an error trying to
  log you in: ''**, there is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245505/abp-io-blazor-template-tenant-login-fails-without-error-message) which is not
  answered.

Looking at logs indicates that there are some issues with Identity Server, however, I am unable to resolve the issue. Tried clearing browser cache but that didn't help.

Thanks in advance, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Already found the reason https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/7518#issuecomment-769657228

Comment: I raised that issue with abp, it seems to be working now with version 4.2.2.